# get first 2 values in a comma separated string

Tags: scala

I am trying to get the first 2 values of a comma separated string in scala. For example

```
a,b,this is a test
```

How do i store the values a,b in 2 separate variables?

Comment: What if there's fewer than 2 elements in your String?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To keep it easy and clean.

**KISS solution:**

1.Use **split** for separation. Then use **take** which is defined on all ordered sequences to get the elements as needed:

```
scala> val res = "a,b,this is a test" split ',' take 2
res: Array[String] = Array(a, b)
```

2.Use Pattern matching to set the variables:

```
scala> val Array(x,y) = res
x: String = a
y: String = b*
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution using `Sequence Pattern match` in Scala[enter link description here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/122.html)

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val str = "a,b,this is a test"
str: String = a,b,this is a test

scala> val Array(x, y, _*) = str.split(",")
x: String = a
y: String = b


scala> println(s"x = $x, y = $y")
x = a, y = b
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for the method `split` ?

```
"a,b,this is a test".split(',')
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, this is a test)
```

If you want only the first two values you'll need to do something like:

```
val splitted = "a,b,this is a test".split(',')
val (first, second) = (splitted(0), splitted(1))
```

Comment: You won't need to do something like that. See the other answers for idiomatic pattern on the LHS of assignment.

Answer (score 2):

There should be some regex options here.

```
scala> val s = "a,b,this is a test"
s: String = a,b,this is a test

scala> val r = "[^,]+".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = [^,]+

scala> r findAllIn s
res0: scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator = non-empty iterator

scala> .toList
res1: List[String] = List(a, b, this is a test)

scala> .take(2)
res2: List[String] = List(a, b)

scala> val a :: b :: _ = res2
a: String = a
b: String = b
```

but

```
scala> val a :: b :: _ = (r findAllIn "a" take 2).toList
scala.MatchError: List(a) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
  ... 33 elided
```

or if you're not sure there is a second item, for instance:

```
scala> val r2 = "([^,]+)(?:,([^,]*))?".r.unanchored
r2: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = ([^,]+)(?:,([^,]*))?

scala> val (a,b) = "a" match { case r2(x,y) => (x, Option(y)) }
a: String = a
b: Option[String] = None

scala> val (a,b) = s match { case r2(x,y) => (x, Option(y)) }
a: String = a
b: Option[String] = Some(b)
```

This is a bit nicer if records are long strings.

Footnote: the Option cases look nicer with a [regex interpolator.](https://github.com/som-snytt/regextractor/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/regex/GrTest.scala#L154)

Answer (score 1):

If your string is short, you may as well just use `String.split` and take the first two elements.

```
val myString = "a,b,this is a test"
val splitString = myString.split(',') // Scala adds a split-by-character method in addition to Java's split-by-regex
val a = splitString(0)
val b = splitString(1)
```

Another solution would be to use a regex to extract the first two elements. I think it's quite elegant.

```
val myString = "a,b,this is a test"
val regex = """(.*),(.*),.*""".r    // all groups (in parenthesis) will be extracted.
val regex(a, b) = myString          // a="a", b="b"
```

Of course, you can tweak the regex to only allow non-empty tokens (or anything else you might need to validate) :

```
val regex = """(.+),(.+),.+""".r
```

Note that in my examples I assumed that the string always had at least two tokens. In the first example, you can test the length of the array if needed. The second one will throw a MatchError if the regex doesn't match the string.

---

I had originally proposed the following solution. I will leave it because it works and doesn't use any class formally marked as deprecated, but the Javadoc for [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) mentions that it is a legacy class and should no longer be used.

```
val myString = "a,b,this is a test"
val st = new StringTokenizer(",");
val a = st.nextToken()
val b = st.nextToken()
// You could keep calling st.nextToken(), as long as st.hasMoreTokens is true
```

Comment: Did you see the part where it says: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code.

Comment: Actually, I didn't. I guess that means that a proper solution would use a regex - I'll edit my answer with one.